# StringBuilder dobles comillas dentro de dobles comillas que a su vez están dentro de dobles comillas

Tags: c#

Dentro de un string tengo parte de un codigo html con un onclick que llama a una función. El problema es que  uso  doble comillas dentro de dobles comillas que a su vez tienen doble comillas y cuando se lo paso al objeto stringBuilder para construir luego la pagina el codigo html no me lo construye bien.

El codigo html que va dentro del string seria este:

```
string codigo = "<div class='dropright'>" + 
"<button type='button' onclick='__doPostBack(\"variableUno\",\"1\");'>" + 
 numeroBoton + 
"</button>" +
"</div>"
```

Entonces con StringBuilder preparo el string para pasarlo a un formato de objeto json que sera un array de arrays. El codigo me funciona bien si quito la parte del `onclick='__dopostback('variableUno','1')'`

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("[[");
sb.Append("\"" + codigo + "\"");
sb.Append("]]");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solución:**  En la cadena original hay que escapar también el slash `\`.

Quedando así:

```
onclick='__doPostBack(\\\"variableUno\\\",\\\"1\\\")
```

Los primeros dos `\\` insertan un slash y lo que sigue `\"` inserta la comilla.

**Explicación:**

La salida actual del `StringBuilder` es esta:

```
[["<div class='dropright'><button type='button' onclick='__doPostBack("variableUno","1");'>1</button></div>"]]
```

Cuando hizo la concatenación reemplazó los `\"` de la cadena original por una comilla, eso es correcto pero produce error al convertirlo a json porque las comillas internas no están siendo escapadas.

La salida debería ser así:

```
[["<div class='dropright'><button type='button' onclick='__doPostBack(\"variableUno\",\"1\");'>1</button></div>"]]
```

Para que las comillas en la salida final estén escapadas se debe conservar el slash `\` antes de la comilla.

Comment: Correcto !! Funciona perfectamente ! Muchas gracias !